# Hamachi disables after system lock

Tags: hamachi

I have the problem since yesterday. When I'm logged on the computer hamachi works OK, I have the connection in my network. But after I lock the computer I cannot have the connection to it. Suddenly after I log to the computer it connects again.

Can somebody help me with that issue? I tried a lot, the hamachi system service works ok, I even reinstalled the software...

Answer (score 5):

There was a change in the licensing. Basically they decided their product was too useful and cool for people not to pay for it. The change in the licensing reads:

> unless a computer is part of a paid network, you need to be logged in
>   and running the Hamachi UI on your desktop in order to allow it to
>   function

Basically this closed free access to using Hamachi to log onto unattended computers, but allowed casual users (like gamers) to continue using it for free.

Notice about changes in the licensing can be found at: [Changes to Hamachi on November 19th](http://b.logme.in/2012/11/07/changes-to-hamachi-on-november-19th/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130306103206/http://b.logme.in/2012/11/07/changes-to-hamachi-on-november-19th/)); some people got really pissed off at the change. The change seems fair to me, but it's a pity they're no longer free to access unattended computers. I haven't been on the hunt for a free alternative yet. In a discussion at superuser, [someone](https://superuser.com/questions/526633/how-can-i-run-hamachi-as-a-service) recommended [NeoRouter](http://www.neorouter.com/), but I haven't tested it yet; seems like a good option though.